# Initializing and inserting nested JSON data in Golang?

Tags: json, go

I've been at my wits end attempting to get this to work for the last 3 hours, so hopefully you guys will be able to help me with this.

I'm attempting to initialize a nested JSON structure in Go and insert data into it. This is the structure of the JSON that I'm looking to process:

```
{
  "top": {
    "item1": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "item2": "This is item2",
    "item3": "This is item3",
    "item4": {
      "foo2": "bar2"
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I am setting it up in Go --

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func main() {

data := make(map[string]map[string]map[string]string) // init top level map
data["top"] = make(map[string]map[string]string)
data["top"]["item1"] = make(map[string]string)
data["top"]["item4"] = make(map[string]string)


data["top"]["item1"]["foo"] = "bar"
data["top"]["item4"]["foo2"] = "bar2"
data["top"]["item2"] = "This is item2"


fmt.Println(data)
}
```

However, if I run this, I get this error:

*cannot use "This is item2" (type string) as type map[string]string in assignment*

I'm sure I'm making this overly complicated, so what would be the more efficient way of expressing this?

Comment: You should use structs, rather than nested maps.

Comment: A struct would definitely be easier. Barring that, you'd need to use a `map[string]interface{}` if the values in your interface aren't the same type.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of using structs instead of nested maps. I was able to get it working by using a similar example described by this link:
https://medium.com/@xcoulon/nested-structs-in-golang-2c750403a007

Answer (score 2):

Using nested maps can get a little confusing, so perhaps using a struct would help make working with your data structure more manageable.

Consider using a tool like [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to help you construct proper objects for your JSON data.

**Note:** *This will not provide a perfect struct each time- in fact, often this tool will simply default to using the interface type when it is unable to identify the proper type (which is not ideal), so you'll need to likely customize the output, but overall it will provide you with a good starting point.*

Working example in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZtPrhIocudK)